# How to Change Number Format of a Cell Based on Its Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have values in `column B` that cahnge based on the ticker present in `column A`

```
1 |VIX   |     24.14
2 |NQ    |    12,141
```

this can become this

```
1 |SPX   |  2,000.50
2 |US10Y |         0
```

Every time I change to a ticker with different precision, I have to manually modify the `Number Format` to accomodate the best visualisation.
For instance with the change above the new `Number Format` should become:

```
1 |SPX   |     2,000
2 |US10Y |     0.005
```

How can I make a custom formula or script that changes the `Number Format` based on how big the number is?
In a googlesheet pseudo script language it should be something like:

```js
changesNumberFormat(cell) {
  let value = cell.value
  if (value > 100) {
    cell.numberFormat("#,##0")
  } elseif (value < 0.1) {  
    cell.numberFormat("0.###")
  } else {cell.numberFormat("0.#")}
}
```

I told it would have been something straight forward but I can't evenunderstand how to take the value of the cell where the formula is applied to.

Comment: It can be done pretty easy with `onEdit()` trigger. But it will work only when you make changes on the sheet manually. If the values are changed by formulas the trigger doesn't fire. You have to run the script manually then. Via a custom menu, for example.

Comment: thanks, I will try, but how do I get the value of each cell to make the check on the number of whole digits? so far I could only find how to get selected cell, I don't understand how to get each value of each cell to which the script will be applied on

Comment: I just added the example how to change formatting for a range.

Comment: I believe what you are doing is using something like GOOGLEFINANCE to get the current quote for a stock symbol.  When you change the symbol the cell next to it is updated.  Since that cell is a formula you really have to add another column next to it to reformat the number, either through onEdit() or a custom formula using Number.toFixed().  You can hide the column the formulas are in.

Comment: I am using a series of `importxml()` in many googlesheets to avoid queries limitation. I then import all of those in a mother spreadsheet with a long list in sheet ::import, I then fetch from that list in the ::main sheet with a `VLOOKUP()` that checks for the ticker in the adjacent cell through the long list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script doesn't seem to be necessary. You can set the number format for the entire data range with [meta instructions](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats?hl=en#meta_instructions):

> [condition]    Replaces the default positive, negative, or zero comparison of the section with another conditional expression. For example, [<100]”Low”;[>1000]”High”;000 will render the word “Low” for values below 100, “High” for values above 1000 and a three digit number (with leading 0s) for anything in between. Conditions can only be applied to the first two sub-formats and if a number matches more than one, it will use the first one it matches. If there is a third format, it will be used for "everything else", otherwise if a number doesn’t match either format, it will be rendered as all "#"s filling up the cell width. The fourth format is always used for text, if it exists.

#### Solution:

```
[>100]#,##0;[<0.1]0.###;0.#
```

Comment: that's what I thought at first, but then I was trying to enter 4 options and it was telling me that it was invalid, so I thought it was not working at all.. now I understand it's fine if only 3 options are given? Do you know if it is possible to add more options rathe than just three?

Comment: @user3755529 The docs are explicit. Only two meta instructions are allowed. Four options can be present, but only the first two can have meta instructions and the fourth will ALWAYS be used for Text, the third one is the catch all -default clause for numbers. So, No.

Comment: the should make it more expressive. anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3755529 You can always provide feedback on the top of the linked page for documentation feedback or in the sheets web app, if that's instructions in the help section is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the values manually you can format them with `onEdit()` trigger this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 1) return; // if it's not column A do nothing

  var value = e.value;
  var cell = e.range;
  if (value > 100)      cell.setNumberFormat("#,##0");
  else if (value < 0.1) cell.setNumberFormat("0.###");
  else                  cell.setNumberFormat("0.#");
}
```

It changes formatting in column A. Perhaps it makes sense to limit the script to work on just one sheet only.

It doesn't work if the values are changing not manually.

**Update**

Here is the example how to set formatting for a range:

```
function changesNumberFormat_for_range() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:B10');
  var values = range.getValues();

  for (let row in values) for (let col in values[row]) {
    var value = values[row][col];
    var cell = sheet.getRange(1+ +row,1+ +col);
    if (value > 100)      cell.setNumberFormat("#,##0");
    else if (value < 0.1) cell.setNumberFormat("0.###");
    else                  cell.setNumberFormat("0.#");
  }
}
```

But it can work very slow for big ranges since it calls `getRange()` for every single cell in the range.

Comment: I get this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined`, I put in Google AppsScript from my googlesheet, if I modify column a, column B doesn't change format despite folowing a change in precision

Comment: Are you using GOOGLEFINANCE?

Comment: As for the error I assume you're trying to run this function from Script Editor. It doesn't work this way. It fires automatically every time you edit the sheet. As for the column B, if you want to change cells in columns A and B you can change the condition in first like this way: `if (e.range.columnStart > 2) return;` If you want to change any columns you can just remove (or comment out) this line.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, I even tried to add `e.setValue("hello")` but nothing changes, even though I am setting the correct number in the first if statement. Not sure why.

Comment: If you want 'hello' it should be `e.range.setValue('hello')`. As for the rest I'm not sure, too. Probably I could to figure it out if you show how your sheet looks like. Here is my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oEJhWXwwJiZp7jxK_Bb8jIIgydm44NT7QMTaensKQYw/edit?usp=sharing